# how to add a new variable to a list of file

Tags: r

If I want to build a variable `ID`with `STUDYID`+`SUBJECT` for all the dataset with name `_OK` in my environment, what should I do?
I can think of

```
list<-mget(ls(pattern = "_OK$"))
```

then I can I create new var `ID` for all data.frames  that with name `_OK`? I think lapply or map should work, but i am not sure how to use those two. Could someone help me set an example?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to build a variable ID with STUDYID+SUBJECT`. Can you show an example?

Comment: i have a list of data.frame: a_ok, b_ok, c_ok,I want to add ID to each of them. so I will have a_ok$ID, b_ok$ID at hte end, and they are build using studyid and subject.

Comment: What should be the value in the `ID` variable? Do you want to combine studyid and subject together in one column?

Comment: mutate(ID = paste(STUDYID,SUBJECT,sep = "-"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
list_data <-mget(ls(pattern = "_OK$"))

lapply(list_data, function(x) transform(x,ID = paste(STUDYID,SUBJECT,sep = "-")))
```

Or using `tidyverse` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(list_data, ~.x %>% mutate(ID = paste(STUDYID,SUBJECT,sep = "-")))
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit on why we need 'transform`? Thanks

Comment: `tranform` is a base R used to add a new column in the dataframe. The benefit of it is we don't have to use dataframe$column_name to refer to column name like other base R functions. It behaves the same way as `mutate`.